Two 30 amp manual transfer switch with 50 amp inlet & 12500 KW generator
I have a portable generator 12500 KW with a 50 and 30 AMP connection. I have an inlet box 50 AMP. I have 2 manual transfer switch 30 amp and 10 gauged wire. The 2 switches have 10G wire each that connect to the inlet. wires run about 100 or so ft. Professional electrician did the install but it was late and didn't get to test out and didn't check then for a few months. Should be okay with the 50 AMP connection from generator or stick to 30 amp?

Huh? You have 1 inlet with connection to two transfer switches? Ugh. Are those two transfer switches attached to the same breaker panel? Can you provide picture(s) of the panel(s)?

10 gauge is only good for 30 amps in most cases.  The breaker that feeds the wire(generator) is what determines wire size/fire safety.

Can't do that.
If you have 2 or more transfer switches, all but one must switch neutral.
Those hinky, obsolete 6-8-10 circuit "transfer switches" don't even support neutral, let alone neutral switching, so there can be only one of those in the system.
If your requirements exceed that of one transfer switch, your least costly option is to install a generator interlock in the main panel and switch the whole panel, or create a "critical loads" subpanel (38 circuit maximum at sane cost) and use an interlock to switch the whole subpanel between utility and generator.
Then you permanently move the critical circuits into the critical loads sub.  That is, they are not in the main panel anymore and now you have empty breaker spaces there.     If the Romex cabling is going into the main panel, and you are not in Canada, you can just link the main and critical loads sub with several conduits and pass the hot(s) and neutral through the conduit to the critical loads sub.  Ground stays in the panel the Romex enters.
A generator interlock or critical loads subpanel will correctly support AFCI and GFCI, and is safe on MWBC.   Note that if AFCI or GFCI is required, it's required on generator mode too.  This is a failing of many transfer switches.

If you are in the US and under the National Electrical Code the conductors are required to be protected no higher than their maximum current rating and for #10 wire that is 30 amps.
Consequently, you would have to stick with the 30 amp output from the generator unless you increase the size of the transfer switch and conductors.
It is possible the electrician installed two switches to feed two different loads giving you the choice of which one you will to power from the generator.
